# "pergunte ao leigo se...." está errado ? Deveria ser "pergunte a um leigo"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Minha dúvida é sobre o uso de "o leigo" em **ptBR e no seguinte contexto**:

> "Colegas, todos nós sabemos que o tabagista crônico, inveterado, está mais propenso a diversas patologias além daquelas pulmonares e cardiovasculares.  Mas **perguntem ao leigo** se ele tem noção..."
>
> "Nós, médicos, sabemos disso, mas **o leigo** não imagina que..."

[**leigo**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/leigo) - (adjetivo e substantivo masculino)  "que ou quem não tem conhecimentos especializados em determinada área"

Minha dúvida deve-se ao fato de que eu fui corrigido recentemente aqui ao escrever "pergunte ao leigo".

Comment: Não fui eu, juro!! Mas **se** ;) tivesse sido, seria porque "o leigo" era pessoa indeterminada, e por isso deveria levar um artigo indefinido - `um`; se fosse pessoa determinada (aquele leigo ali), então levaria um artigo definido - `o`.

Comment: @ANeves  O leigo refere-se a "aquele que é leigo", da mesma forma que "o rico",  "o pobre", "o valente", "o covarde".   "O covarde não admite que...", "O rico está mais preocupado com seus lucros e dividendos do que...",  "O cínico não hesitaria em.....".

Comment: Em Portugal acho que se usaria "os leigos", nesse caso; ou talvez "um leigo".

Comment: `Em Portugal acho que se usaria [antes]` - parece que em Portugal, afinal, a construção original é aceitável; o @Artefacto esclareceu-me, nos comentários da sua resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pouca gente terá dúvidas a respeito do segundo exemplo que dás, do género destoutro que podemos encontrar no CETEMPúblico:

> (1) Para o leigo, o ‘poeta’ está muito acima do ‘banqueiro’.

Estas frases são muito semelhantes a estas outras:

> (2) Para os leigos, o ‘poeta’ está muito acima do ‘banqueiro’.
>   (3) Para um leigo, o ‘poeta’ está muito acima do ‘banqueiro’.

Todas elas representam contextos frásicos genéricos. Esta genericidade não depende do tipo do sintagma nominal (definido ou não). A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (2003, vol. I, pág. 809) identifica o trabalho de Krifka e outros (incluído no livro [*The Generic Book*](http://www.worldcat.org/title/generic-book/oclc/31045869&referer=brief_results)) como um importante contributo para a interpretação deste tipo de frases (ditas **caracterizadoras**, porque representam properiedades gerais ou habituais) e dá os seguintes exemplos:

> a. *Toda a criança* chora quando tem fome.
>   b. *Muitas pessoas* não dormem oito horas por dia.
>   c. *A maior parte as pessoas* vive sem se perguntar para quê.
>   d. *Geralmente*, *os portugueses* são trabalhadores.
>   e. Por norma, *o alemão* gosta de ceveja. [nota de rodapé: Com um exemplo semelhante, usando também o [sintagma nominal] definido *o alemão*, Lopes (1972) descreveu o tipo de interpretação em causa como envolvendo o «alemão típico».
>   f. *Algumas pessoas* não fazem uma multidão.

Por outro lado, «perguntem ao leigo», sem mais, não é equivalente a «perguntem a um leigo»:

> (4) Ontem encontrei-me com um leigo; perguntei **ao leigo** se ele concordava.
>   (5) Ontem, perguntei a **um leigo** se ele concordava.

O que legitima na tua frase que possas usar **o leigo** é o facto de este ter um valor genérico; caso contrário *o* teria de referir-se a uma pessoa em particular. Ter valor genérico só por si não é suficiente para ser indiferente qual o determinante a usar. Por exemplo, em contexto genéricos não caracterizadores, como as frases episódicas, só o determinante definido pode ser usado (pág. 850, exemplo daí):

> (6) *O chocolate*/**Um chocolate* foi introduzido na Europa pelos espanhóis.

Em todo o caso, creio estarmos perante uma frase caracterizadora. O teu exemplo não está completo, mas se o completarmos podemos ver que estamos a descrever uma cracterística dos leigos:

> (7) Mas perguntem ao leigo se ele tem noção disto e ele dir-vos-á que não fazia ideia.

Ou parafraseando:

> (8) O leigo não faz ideia de que o tabagista crônico não está apenas mais exposto a patalogias pulmonares e cardiovasculares.

Comment: Em pt-PT, a frase a) não é usada; a frase e) seria no plural... exceto no caso de "o alemão típico", em que acho que seria usada no singular. :( Se calhar vou ter de abrir uma versão pt-PT desta pergunta...

Comment: @ANeves Estás equivocado. A _Gramática do Português_ descreve  essencialmente a variante portuguesa e todas as frases me parecem completamente admissíveis. Exemplo para a 1a (CETEMPúblico): _«Todo o português passará a receber os impostos e a entregar ao Estado os seus rendimentos, ordenados ou salários._ Podes quando muito dizer que são menos comuns que outras alternativas.

Comment: Ora, parece mesmo que estou equivocado. Soa-me mesmo muito estranha, essa variante.

Comment: Uma respsta clara e didática, e uma bela redação. (pelo menos na minha opinião)